# Token authentication in django . Credentials are correct whch are already saved in database but still token is not generating

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

Hi I'm stuck with a problem that the credentials are correct in database but still it is printing the the "else" condition that "Invalid email or password". Help me out I'm stuck with this problem.

I've tried  to setup AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND in "settings.py" file. But it is not the solution here.

```
    class LoginAPIView(views.APIView):
        def post(self, request):
            email = request.data["email"]
            password = request.data["password"]
    
            serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
            print(serializer)
    
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            
    
            if serializer.is_valid():
                if user is not None:
                    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                    return Response({
                        'data': serializer.data,
                        'token': token.key
                    })
                else:
                    return Response({
                        'errors': 'Invalid email or password.'
                    }, status=400)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

views.py code

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password']
```

User Serializer code

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            age=validated_data['age'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            country=validated_data['country'],
            hobby=validated_data['hobby'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

I know the issue is with the authentication method but I can't figure it out how to solve the problem .also I have already checked the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting in my settings.py file, and it seems to be correctly configured. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using `email` instead of `username`? Are you using a custom User model with `email` field as unique?

Comment: Yes I'm using email instead of username and email is unique. also I'm using a custom user model

Comment: Would you be able to check if the serializer is getting validated or are there any errors? 
`serializer.is_valid` returns True or False? Also, can you print the value of `user` after the authenticate method.

Comment: Yes 've print the value of user it returns None . serializer.is_valid() is validated as i've print the serializer for verification whether it is getting validated or not

Comment: Are you still using the default `authenticate` method which is imported from `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`. That works only with `username` and `password`

Comment: yes I'm still using this method . okay so instead of email should i go with username ?

Comment: Also i've changed the "email" to "username". It gives me key error of "username" in postman

Comment: I've put an answer below assuming that you are only using emails in your application. If you are using both username as well as email then you may need to edit that custom authenticate method to include that logic as well.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using the default `authenticate` method from `django.contrib.auth import authenticate` which works only with `username` and `password`.

You may need to write a custom `authenticate` function and use that instead.

```
def authenticate(email=None, password=None):
    try:

        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        else:
            return None
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working

Comment: Could you provide another code with the authenticate method

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: can you please confirm me one thing should I've to replace this method with django authenticate method?

Comment: you need to remove the import `django.contrib.auth import authenticate` and use this function instead. You can put this function in the same file.

Comment: Okay just give me few mins i'll update you

Comment: It s not working properly can you provide me another method?

Comment: I'm ready for session

Comment: https://meet.google.com/pfh-hynp-tci here you go

Comment: can you please share the link again?